# Bug regards Django adds extension/folder name to image stored on AmazonS3

Tags: django, image, amazon-s3, upload

I have a major bug in production, my image file extension keeps adding another folder on AmazonS3. An example is posted below. I just defined a regular image field in my model. But somehow it keeps adding new folder and name extension to the image file. I have no clue why this loop occurs.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts/", null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
```

It's give:

> media/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/Nordi.jpg

Comment: Try losing the `/`, just `upload_to="posts"`

Also, why do you have `max_length` on a `ImageField`?

Comment: I tried to define a max_length to the path keeps adding up, but it seems like a bad solution at all.. I will try to remove / .                                                           
Storage tried to truncate away entire filename “posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/posts/Nordi.jpg”. Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient “max_length”.